# unhashable type : 'list'

Tags: python, django

I am porting application from django 1.8 and python 2.7 to django 2.2 AND PYTHON 3.6

this was in python 2.7

```
 def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('threads_reply', [self.id])
    get_absolute_url = models.permalink(get_absolute_url)
```

i changed it too

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return django.urls.resolve('threads_reply', [self.id])
```

And its now crashing at this

```
@login_required
def inbox(request, template_name='django_messages/inbox.html'):
    """
    Displays a list of received messages for the current user.
    Optional Arguments:
        ``template_name``: name of the template to use.
    """
    thread_list = Thread.objects.inbox_for(request.user)
    return render(request, template_name, {
        'thread_list': thread_list,
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`resolve()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/urlresolvers/#resolve) is not expecting list as second argument. This function using for resolving URL paths to the corresponding view functions e.g.:

```
match = resolve('/some/path/')
# Print the URL pattern that matches the URL
print(match.url_name)
```

As for your case I suppose you are looking for [`reverse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse):

```
from django.urls import reverse

def get_absolute_url(self):
    reverse('threads_reply', args=[self.id])
```

Which does opposite thing. It reverse view name to URL.

Comment: @user3278732 hm, can you add full traceback to the question?

Comment: Also ca you add `inbox_for` method?

Comment: Looks like you missed `args` in reverse call. It should be `reverse('threads_reply', args=[self.id])` instead of `reverse('threads_reply', [self.id])`.